Gatling Scala - POST call to a http url with body is giving j.i.IOException: Premature close error
I am trying to call an url (POST) and submit some form data. The body type is - "x-www-form-urlencoded"
Code snippet:
  val sentHeadersSim = Map(
    "Accept" -> "*/*",
    "Content-Type" -> "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=ISO-8859-1"
  )

 .exec(http("simulator POST call")
        .post("[http://example.com:8000/sim](https://stackoverflow.com)")
        .headers(sentHeadersSim)
        .formParam("param1", "testdata1")
        .formParam("param2", "testdata2")
        .formParam("param3", "testdata3")
        .formParam("param4", "testdata4")
        .formParam("param5", "testdata5")
        .check(status.is(200))

Error I am getting - io.gatling.http.client.impl.HttpAppHandler$1: Premature close j.i.IOException: Premature close error. It seems server is closing the connection before response is received.
The call is working fine in Postman and I am getting 200 ok.
In gatling scala it seems the request is being made without proper request form body. In the log I see below details, and after that NO response is received from the server and connection closed.
HTTP request:
POST http://example.com:8000/sim
headers:
    Accept: */*
    Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    host: example.com:8000
    content-length: 73

body:FormUrlEncodedRequestBody{patchedContentType='null', charset=UTF-8, content=param1=testdata1&param2=testdata2&param3=testdata3&param4=testdata4&param5=testdata5
}

Could you please help if I am missing something.

"The call is working fine in Postman" Consider showing us the equivalent curl command.

@GeorgeLeung - The issue was by default Gatling is sending Content-Length header as lower case ( Ex: content-length: 73 ), but our server handles that as case sensitive. so when explicitly added "Content-Length" -> "-1" in our header , It worked.

Your server behaves in a way that's a clear violation of the HTTP specification. Header names are case insensitive, see https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.2. Your server must be fixed.
